# Can I run Lua interpreter in evaluator mode?

Tags: lua, interpreter, evaluator

Many of script interpreters like `irb` or `node` works as evaluator. If I execute this code,

```
10
```

it will evaluate and print the value itself, and make no error.

When I installed `lua` it worked as executor rather than evaluator. So when I put `10`, it will make an error.

Can I make the Lua interpreter work as evaluator?

Comment: `10` by itself isn't valid lua syntax, so I don't see how you'd make that happen.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Carl Sorry. There was a big mistyping. Sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's also [iLua](https://github.com/ilua/ilua). It is an extended interpreter and does pretty much all you want.

Answer (score 10):

There is no such thing as "evaluator mode". The Lua interpreter only interprets valid Lua code. That is except for one exception, that is lines starting with `=`.

In the stand alone interpreter, you have this shortcut to start a line with `=` , which translates to `return`. And in the interpreter, when a value gets returned to the "main" routine, it gets printed.

So these are effectively equivalent when entered at the command line:

```
= 10, 22
return 10, 22
print(10, 22)
```